# Format for curl command

Tags: php, curl, shell-exec

I am new to curl. I just wanted to check whether the format is correct or not. I am getting
error is like

****Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /** for the followinw curl command

```
$curl="curl -i -X POST -d '{ "mac": ".$clientMAC.", "ap":".$ap.", "url": ".$url.", "session": { "email": ".$email.", "first_name": ".$fname.", ".$lname.": "user_last_name" } }' -H "Content-Type: text/html";
shell_exec($curl);
```

How can I fix it. Please help me

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the [`curl_*`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) functions instead?

Comment: Escape your `"` quotes, use an editor which shows syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

I made this function:

```
function makeCurlRequest($_url, $_data)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
    $curl, 
    array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $_url,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $_data
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $resp;
}
```

It takes the url and an associative array to POST and returns the result